# Error:resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I just updated the build.gradle compile SDK to 27 API.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 27
```

but but once I hit sync button it throws

```
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka  {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

but the build process was ok with SDK 26

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Previously:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification"
```

Now the following is correct:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification"
```

Since:

> ```
> compileSdkVersion 27
> buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" 
> minSdkVersion 19 
> targetSdkVersion 27
> ```

Comment: where to add this line android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification" ??

Comment: Please explain more about it @jhandei

Comment: @Quicklearner take a look to [my answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406018/2232889), maybe it helps you

Comment: in every text view?

Comment: where to make this change?

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I solved it by deleting all cached libraries from  Gradle on:

```
\{userFolder}\.gradle\caches
```

[image: delete cached libraries in windows]

Comment: In my case, the build failure seemed to happen after no real change to code or migration to a new SDK, I was moving around projects quite a bit.  I also got several strange locked file messages.  Regardless, clearing this cache solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

in my case i have added this line in gradle if u still want to use support libraries instead of AndroidX

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```