# Xamarin: No resources found that matches the given name TextAppearance.Compat.Notification after migrating targetSDK to 27

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library, build-error, target-sdk

I migrated my Xamarin.Android project to target sdk 27 and then updated all nuget packages to new versions. While building i received some errors i wasn't able to fix:

```
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values\values.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title'.
C:\Users\...path...\Droid\obj\DebugTest\MonoAndroid81\lp\34\jl\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title'.
```

My nuget dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity" version="3.3.2.33" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="AWSSDK.Core" version="3.3.25.2" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="AWSSDK.SecurityToken" version="3.3.4.14" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService" version="3.3.1.10" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Fabric.Core" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid51" />
<package id="Fabric.Crashlytics" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid51" />
<package id="Genetics" version="1.1.0.50" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="modernhttpclient" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="PCLCrypto" version="2.0.147" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="MonoAndroid51" />
<package id="PInvoke.BCrypt" version="0.5.155" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="PInvoke.Kernel32" version="0.5.155" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="PInvoke.NCrypt" version="0.5.155" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="PInvoke.Windows.Core" version="0.5.155" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Validation" version="2.4.18" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common" version="1.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common" version="1.0.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime" version="1.0.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="27.0.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.11" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Common" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.Impl" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.TagManager.V4.Impl" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="60.1142.1" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
</packages>
```

Any Solutions?
I didn't know how to fix it. I tried clean locals, obj, bin dirs on windows and mac and rebuild, nothing works. None of compat notifications styles is not used by me in code.

min sdk - 15
target sdk - 27

Xamarin.Android SDK 9.0.0.1.9
Visual Studio 2017

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the min, compile and target versions set on manifest file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka {packageId}.test:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241620/errorresource-style-textappearance-compat-notification-info-aka-packageid-te)

Comment: @Prateek min 15, target 27, compile? I didn't see this options in xamarin.
Topic that you share is similar but not same, because i don't use this styles in my codebase. They seem to be used in one of the library.

Comment: you will see `compile using` option in Project -> right click -> Properties -> Application . To check if the issue is similar check in Resources/values/styles.xml theme should reference to Theme.AppCompat..... themes

Comment: @Prateek compile is 27 too

Comment: update APKs by opening SDK manager also share styles.xml content

Comment: my base theme use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as parent

Comment: Hey @marcu, did you figure out what was wrong? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @ValeriyKovalenko Unfortunately i don't remember, probably i have finally build application by clearing update'ing everything many times and completely removing and installing xamarin few times, but i'm not sure. I moved to native android programming and i didn't use xamarin any more, to buggy